# How do I connect to my Github Repo and push changes to the repo through VScode?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, connect

I Can't connect to an existing Git Repo on Github through VScode on a new machine. Unsure of how to login in order to access repo and push changes.

I have a Git repo setup which was initially setup on my desktop at home. I am currently away from my desktop and will be for awhile and therefore was looking to do some work through my laptop. I have VScode installed on my laptop and was able to download my most recent push to the master branch through github and open the folder. I went ahead and downloaded Git but cannot figure out how to login into my github account through the terminal and start tracking changes and committing to my master branch through my laptop like I am/was able to on my desktop machine.

I had found a guide previously which walked through the process of setting it up on my desktop but cannot find how to connect and contribute to an existing repo through VScode.

If anyone has an idea of what steps I need to go through to connect to an existing repo and start tracking changes, staging and eventually pushing to a new branch or the master branch through the terminal in VScode that would be great. Thank you!

As a side note, I attempted:

```
git config --global user.name "github userID"
git clone "URL from github link copied earlier"
```

but I am not seeing the changes I make being tracked in VScode therefore nothing to stage or push.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what isn't working, and what error message or bad situation you're seeing?

Comment: I was initially having an issue where I was unable to clone my repo and by extension not track any changes while coding in VScode- and due that that unable to use git push or any other git command to make changes or contribute to the repo or project. I was looking to get clarity on the steps needed through VScode utilizing the terminal to clone an existing repo on GitHub and contribute to it through VScode i.e. git push, fetch etc..

Comment: What is the output from `git clone "URL from github link copied earlier"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that, from VSCode, you are modifying files that are in the local folder of the cloned repository.

Double-check that a `git status` (in command line) done in that folder does show modified files, making sure they are not ignored.